# How to change default datasource name in wildfly-swarm

Tags: wildfly-swarm

How to set default Data source name (say MyDS). 
Swarm is always taking "ExampleDS" as defaultDatasource.

with earlier versions it used to be something like this

```
container.fraction(new PostgreSQLJPAFraction()
        .inhibitDefaultDatasource()
        .defaultDatasource("jboss/datasources/MyDS")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the datasource name to be used with `swarm.ds.property` variable via -D on command line or with a yaml configuration file.

Full details can be found here: https://wildfly-swarm.gitbooks.io/wildfly-swarm-users-guide/content/common/jpa.html